# Why does filling a new Window from a div remove the div in the original document?

Tags: javascript, dom, html, prototypejs, observer-pattern

I'm having a big problem the last days with filling in the window **(Resizeable-Draggable Prototype-UI window)** content with Prototype.
I have finally found a working example of what I'm trying to do but it uses some kind of "Windows Plugin" for prototype which i don't use so basically i just want to ask how to compile their code to fit the normal prototype.

What I'm trying to do is to have a window with content pulled from a DIV in the body and the problem is that after i open the window once - The div is deleted and i can't re-open the window.

Here is their working code:

```
if (contentWin != null) {
  Dialog.alert("Close the window 'Test' before opening it again!",{width:200, height:130}); 
}
else {
  contentWin = new Window({maximizable: false, resizable: false, hideEffect:Element.hide, showEffect:Element.show, minWidth: 10, destroyOnClose: true})
  contentWin.setContent('test_content', true, true)
  contentWin.show();    

  // Set up a windows observer, check ou debug window to get messages
  myObserver = {
    onDestroy: function(eventName, win) {
      if (win == contentWin) {
        $('container').appendChild($('test_content'));
        contentWin = null;
        Windows.removeObserver(this);
      }
      debug(eventName + " on " + win.getId())
    }
  }
  Windows.addObserver(myObserver);
}
```

Here is the one i have (I can't open it more than once per refresh):

```
         function openCappAR() {
      var cApp = new UI.Window({theme: "ultra_dark",
      width:  360, 
           height: 350,
           superflousEffects: superflousEffects}).center().show();
           cApp.setContent(
           $('ceBlock').setStyle({
            display: 'inherit'
})
)
    cApp.header.update("Create an App");   
     }
```

Basically i need the DIV to get back to his first version when the window is closed.
I think that Javascript have Observers too so ill add a JS tag if I'm wrong fix me :)

**EDIT: Basically what i need is a window that i will be able to re-open after i close it, the main problem now is when i open a new window it removes the div from the the original document and when i close the window there is NO DIV at all.**

Comment: I didn't really understand your question, but I tried to give it a better title. Feel free to revert if it does not fit. (And consider editing your question so it is easier understandable.)

Comment: Well, i think your title fits the question more than mine, ill edit the question now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up Prototype UI I realized that you're not talking about opening an *real* window, but rather a moveable window-like element on the page. That's rather important to note.

Anyway, if I understood your question (and I'm not sure I did), I'd imagine that you can just clone the div element, and use the clone in the window. That would leave the original div untouched and still in place.

```
var windowContent = $('ceBlock').clone(true);
windowContent.setStyle({ display: 'inherit' });
cApp.setContent(windowContent);
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work. Just note, that `clone` doesn't clone or copy any event listeners you have on the element, so you'll have to add those again, if you have any.

---

Edit: [Prototype's `clone` method](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/clone/) is mostly just an alias for [the browser's built-in `cloneNode` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode). So if you can't use Prototype's method, you should be able to do this instead:

```
// use the standard DOM method
var windowContent = $('ceBlock').cloneNode(true);

// use the dollar function to ensure that the cloned element has been extended by Prototype
$(windowContent).setStyle({ display: 'inherit' });

cApp.setContent(windowContent);
```

Comment: I was really happy with your answer until i tested it out and that's what web console trowed out:$("ceBlock").clone is not a function. And yes bro you understood the question perfectly.

Comment: Well after more digging i have found that i can't use clone because all my system is based on prototype-ui and it doesn't work with prototype versions above 1.6.0 which doesn't have the .clone function. any other suggestions my friend?

Comment: @Ricardo: Alright, if you can't use Prototype's `clone` method, you can use the "real" `cloneNode` method instead. I've updated my answer

Comment: You Are My Hero! But seems like it's not the best way because jQuery doesn't work inside of the windows (it works when i don't clone it) and yea I'm using jQuery noconflict()

Comment: @Ricardo: jQuery should work fine, since the cloned element is just another element. However, `cloneNode` clones everything including the `id` attribute. So after you've run `cloneNode` on `ceBlock`, you'll actually have 2 elements with the id `ceBlock`. It's the same with all the elements inside `ceBlock`: There's 2 of everything. So that might confuse jQuery. Also, as I mentioned, the one thing that _isn't_ cloned is event listners. So if you've set up `$('#ceBlock').click(…)` or something on the original element or its descendants, you'll have to do it again on the cloned element.

Comment: well I'm not a JS guru so ill be grateful if you could help me with the console error: `Empty string passed to getElementById()`. | And an example of the jQuery code: `jQuery("input[name='clientCheck']").change` - While `clientCheck` is a radio inside of the `ceBlock`

Comment: @Ricardo: I'm afraid I can't tell you more than the error message already says: Somehow, somewhere, you or a part of jQuery is trying to call `getElementById` with an empty string as argument. Can't say why that is, though. By the way, an alternative to all this cloning stuff would be to just keep a reference to the original div around as a variable. Instead of trying to find it each time with the `$` function, find it once, and store it. Then pass the stored value to UI.Window. Even when the window closes, the element should still exist in the variable - it just won't be on the page.